# How to add some content or banner thing in jquery mobile before divs with roles page and header with fixed positions

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

How to add some content or banner thing in jquery mobile before divs with roles page and header with fixed positions

```
<div data-role="page" >
 <div class="note">bla bla</div>
 <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
 </div>
</div>
```

I want to show something like notification at very top see div with class note
At the moment note div is present in page source code but nowhere in page display

Comment: JQM has its own page management and is expecting a markup structure like it is described on the docs. You may use an unobtrusive notification plugin (like toastr just as an example) or manage your notifications inside the page content.

Comment: that is not notification ... note div will always be visible

Comment: However solution provided by Muhammad Akber Khan works for me

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Remove data-position="fixed", then div with class="note" will be shown

```
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
```

Comment: it doesn't answer the question.